# Update subdocument by querying sub-subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Gyus, what am I doing wrong?

My schema:

```
const Review = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    text: String,
    author:
    {
        name: String,
        key:
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }
    },
    voting: [ String ]
})

mongoose.model('art', new mongoose.Schema(
{
    ...
    name: String,
    reviews: [ Review ],
    ...
}));
```

MongoDB Shell:

```
db.arts.findOneAndUpdate(
{
    name: "something",
    "reviews.author.key": "581234d3e278e132eb0af8f6"
},
{$addToSet: {"reviews.$.voting": "58123491c08ed174f1f4df74"}});
```

Does what expected. Finds art called "something", then finds subdocument **Review** by author xxx and returns the subdocument to have it updated. 
*Btw, each user can make only one review to each art, so it is safe.*

But equivalent code in nodejs returns empty error. By experimenting, the findOne() with same/similar arguments always returns null. The data, of course, exists - shell returns them.

```
Art.findOneAndUpdate(
{
    name: "something",  
    "reviews.author.key":"581234d3e278e132eb0af8f6"
},
{$addToSet: {"reviews.$.voting": "58123491c08ed174f1f4df74"}},
{new: true});
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

P.S.: Please, stick to Model.method() way. I don't want the code to be slow because of Mongoose framework, triggers etc.

Comment: `"reviews.$.voting": { "key": "58123491c08ed174f1f4df74" }` that's what you called it in your schema. Mongoose strips paths that do not match the schema. But if your "query works in the shell" then your real problem is *"these are not `ObjectId` values, and are simply **strings**"*. So that's why they don't match. You need to fix your data.

Comment: Thank you for that. I edited the question (and my code) accordingly because I don't think that is the problem. My problem is with finding "review.author.key", not updating the "voting" set. But yes, that would probably be the next problem.

Comment: Your not listening. You ran a query in the shell using "plain strings" for the values you have told your schema to be `ObjectId`. The two types are **not the same**. This is why your query returns no results. You either fix the data ( recommended ) or fix the schema. Mongoose is searching for `ObjectId` values that do not exist. They are "strings"!

Comment: You were right. Just your example misguided me. Please, feel free to replicate your comment into answer so I can accept it :)